# NHibernate: How to disable virtual for class properties?

Tags: nhibernate, virtual

how exactly I can use public methods (non-virtual) with NHibernate?

I have this code:

```
public string crewNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.crewNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.crewNumberField = value;
        }
    }
```

Note all my classes, properties, methods and interfaces are auto-generated and I do not want to change them manually.

Above code is producing this error:

> The following types may not be used as
>   proxies: ... method get_crewNumber
>   should be 'public/protected virtual'

I see that it shold be possible to use simple public only properties [here](https://www.hibernate.org/362.html):

> In our example above, we've made the
>   properties and the constructor public
>   - but that's not a requirement for NHibernate - it can use public,
>   protected, internal, or even private
>   properties to persist your data.

How do I turn off this virtual by default?

It's driving me crazy. I am really tempted here to drag one data adapter in visual studio and to end this ridiculous situation once and for all ;-)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I ever had this problem, my properties are not virtual. Can you post a call stack or more details about the error?

Comment: Slavo: what version of NH are you using ?  This behaviour is implemented in a certain version of NH, perhaps you're using an older version that didn't use dynamic proxies ?

Comment: Isn't it easier to change to code generation script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify that dynamic proxies should not be used for that class, by specifying lazy=false on the class-mapping.

Like this:

```
 <class name="MyClass" table="MyTable" lazy="false">
 </class>
```

This means offcourse that you cannot use dynamic proxies with NHibernate.
To be more clear:
- when you retrieve an instance of your class, which is able to use dynamic proxies, you'll recieve an 'empty instance'.  That is, NHibernate will not fetch the data from the DB yet.  You'll get an object who'se Id will be populated, but the other properties are not.  Only when you access a property, then NHibernate will load the data from the DB.  That's the reason why the properties need to be virtual, because NHibernate will create a subclass of your class internally, and override the properties so that it can achieve this behaviour.

I always specify 'lazy=false' on my class-mapping, since I don't want to have virtual properties for a reason that is infrastructure-related, instead of 'domain-related'.

(Note that this has nothing to do with lazy loading of associations; it is still possible to have them lazy loaded when you do not use dynamic proxies).

Comment: Didn't know that. Thought that NHibernate forces 'everything must be virtual' by default. :)

Comment: thank you I am using Fluent so if anybody needs the syntax is:

.Mappings(m => 
                {
                m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<cs_timeslot>().ExportTo(@"C:\temp")
                .Conventions.Add( FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never());

Answer (score 0):

Put `lazy="false"` at the class mapping:

```
<class name="MyClass" table="MY_TABLE" lazy="false">
```